# Atoms of the Lattice of $\ell$-ideals of a lattice ordered group

Tags: ordered-groups

I'm new to lattice groups and I'm stuck in the very first proposition (2.1) of Paul Conrad's paper "Characteristic Subgroups of Lattice-Ordered Groups" (http://www.jstor.org/stable/1995910). Part (c) of the statement says that

"If $A$ is an atom of the lattice of $\ell$-ideals, *and* it is a summand of $G$, then it is simple; moreover if $G$ is representable, then $A$ is linearly ordered."

When I look at the proof, I don't see where $A$ being a summand or where $G$ being representable comes in. Aren't atoms, almost by definition, simple?

Comment: I now understand why atoms need not be simple: An atom $H$ cannot contain subgroups that are normal in $G$, by definition, but it may contain subgroups that are normal in $H$.

Comment: If there are no (proper) disjoint elements, then every convex lattice subgroup is prime, including $0$ by itself. But $\{0\}$ is also an $\ell$-ideal, hence $G$ is isomorphic to $G/\{0\}$ which is totally ordered.

Comment: $G$ has to be representable for the polar $a^\perp$ to be normal.